# select id that occur the most

Tags: sql, oracle, count, max

I have two tables

```
Users(user_id, name)            

Competition(comp_id, user_id, score)
```

I need to select user_id that occur the most in competition.
Can I do it with max(count)?
Is there any way to get exception if two users have same most occurances?

I tried:

```
SELECT MAX(numberr), USER_ID 
FROM ( 
   SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(COMP_ID) AS numberr 
   FROM COMPETITION 
   GROUP BY USER_ID
) 
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

But result I get is:

```
MAX(numberr) USER_ID   
4             1   
2             2   
6             3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done with `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT USER_ID,COUNT(comp_id) as numberr
      FROM COMPETITION
      GROUP BY USER_ID
      ORDER BY COUNT(comp_id) DESC) T1
WHERE rownum=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `not exists`. If there are two users with the same max count, both are presented.

```
with temp as
(
   SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(COMP_ID) AS numberr 
   FROM COMPETITION GROUP BY USER_ID
) 
select *
from temp t 
where not exists (select 1 from temp where numberr > t.numberr)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e649a/5)

Answer (score 0):

To get *multiple* users with the max count use a RANK:

```
SELECT numberr, USER_ID 
FROM ( 
   SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(COMP_ID) AS numberr 
     ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY COUNT(COMP_ID) DESC) rnk
   FROM COMPETITION 
   GROUP BY USER_ID
) dt
WHERE rnk = 1;
```